# Display Images From a file System using Richfaces + Spring Webflow

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf, spring-webflow-2

I am not able to display images from the file system in the xhtmls using `<h:graphicImage`> tag. I am using Spring webflow 2.0 and Richfaces 3.3.3

Should I write a separate servlet to serve the images from the file system ?

I looked into `<a4j:mediaOutput`> tag . Can I use this ? since createContent requires us to specify a method that will be used for content creating. I am unsure if we can use the flow variables/beans to execute methods in the tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can always fetch the images placing under `Web Pages` folder

```
<h:graphicImage url="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}\your_img_path_under_Web_pages" id="img" />
```

If you use `<a4j:mediaOutput>` tag, then yes you should give method in createContent which will draw the image.

```
  <a4j:mediaOutput element="img" createContent="#{serviceBean.method}" value="#{dataBean}" mimeType="image/jpg" />

public void userImage(OutputStream out, Object data) throws IOException {/*your method body*/}
```